# 2 модальных окна на bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Как сделать такую вещь: Есть модельное окно на `bootstrap` с формой. Как при нажатии на кнопку `Отправить` закрыть первое окно, открыть второе и передать параметры формы во второе окно?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.launch-modal').click(function() {
    $('#myModalOption').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: true
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML код кнопки (для отображения модального окна) -->
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary launch-modal" value="Метод modal(парметры)">

<!-- HTML код модального окна-->
<div id="myModalOption" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Подтверждение</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Вы действительно хотите сохранить изменения в документе?</p>
        <p class="text-warning"><small>Если вы не сохраните, изменения будут потеряны.</small>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery или чистый JS? 
И вопрос слишком обширный. Приведите код.

Answer (score 3):

Используя jQuery:

1. скрыть первое окно

   ```
   $("#divId").hide();
   ```
2. открыть второе

   ```
   $("#divId").show();
   ```
3. доступ к параметрам формы во второе окне. Они все всегда доступны, первое просто ведь скрыто, а не закрыто. Их просто нужно получить.

   ```
   $("#ЭлементПараметр").text();
   ```

Comment: Обычное модельное окно на bootstrap с js. Код добавил. Параметры я имею ввиду параметры формы, как их передать из формы в форму?